# Calculate speed given a duration and distance

Tags: r, date, time, lubridate

I have these durations (hours:minutes):

```
duration <- c(00:35, 00:47, 01:38, 02:35, 00:15, 00:45)
```

and these distances (km):

```
distance_in_km <- c(17.46, 16.48, 37.73, 48.9, 15.61, 6.79)
```

How in R can I (1) calculate speed in km/hour and (2) calculate speed in miles/hour? Solutions using the `lubridate` package would be welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of [How work with times, distance and speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480575/how-to-work-with-times-distance-and-speed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the lubridate package you can use something like this. First you have to transform the durations in a character vector.

```
library(lubridate)
duration <- c("00:35", "00:47", "01:38", "02:35", "00:15", "00:45")
d <- hm(duration)
time_length(d,"hour")
[1] 0.5833333 0.7833333 1.6333333 2.5833333 0.2500000 0.7500000
```

Then you can calculate the km/h:

```
distance_in_km <- c(17.46, 16.48, 37.73, 48.9, 15.61, 6.79)
time_in_hours <- time_length(d,"hour")
distance_in_km/time_in_hours
```

and the miles per hour:

```
(distance_in_km*0.621371192)/time_in_hours
```